# j2me connection to spring security

Tags: post, java-me, spring-security

I have an application that use spring security for authentification
I m trying to connect to this application from j2ME midlet

so I am sending an HTTP request from a j2me application using the post method to send username and the password but it doesn't work

the post methode code is fine. it works with other services of the same application (which not require authentification)

but when it comes to authentification I'm getting the response code 302

here is my code

```
        OutputStream os = null;
        HttpConnection connection = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        try {
                connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://localhost:8080/myAppli/j_spring_security_check");
                connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                os = connection.openOutputStream();
                byte data[] =("j_username=appliusername&j_password=applipassword").getBytes();
                os.write(data);
                os.flush();
                int respCode=connection.getResponseCode();

           if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                is = connection.openInputStream();
                if (is != null ) {
                    int ch = -1;
                    while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {

                    sb.append((char)ch);
                     }

               }
          }else {
              System.out.println("Error in opening HTTP Connection. Error#" + respCode);
           }              
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
             try {
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                        //is = null;
                    }
                     if (os != null) {
                        os.close();
                        //is = null;
                    }
                    if (connection != null) {
                        connection.close();
                       // connection = null;
                    }
              }catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the authority part of the URL and change from

```
"http://localhost:8080/myAppli/j_spring_security_check"
```

to

```
"http://appliusername:applipassword@localhost:8080/myAppli/j_spring_security_check"
```

For more information on this, please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Examples

Comment: I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid port format

Comment: it seems it take applipassword@localhost:8080 as port

Comment: Please, also try it on a real device.

Comment: Do this code work with a simple Post service? For example, will a Servlet with doPost method get the j_username and j_password parameters?

Comment: I didn't do it yet but what about this http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?130964-Spring-Security-access-to-a-request-without-pre-authentication-from-remote-access I